# Adding new columns breaks save states in datatables

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am using stateSaveCallback to save the state in a database per logged in user, so then they can save it indefinitely we re-load that data back using stateSaveCallback. It works well, except I notice if we ever add or remove a column in the database, the saved states break. I guess this is because the returned JSON no longer matches the actual columns. This is going to cause huge issues as users save their states, but the system will need ongoing development which would include adding and removing columns.

How can we address this issue so saved states do not break even if columns are added or removed?

For info, here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "date-uk-pre": function (a){
            return parseInt(moment(a, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("X"), 10);
        },
        "date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        },
        "date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
            return b - a;
        }
    });



    var edit_date_col_num = $('th:contains("Edit Date")').index();
    var entry_date_col_num = $('th:contains("Entry Date")').index();

    var table = $('.mainTable').DataTable( {

        pageLength: 20,
        colReorder: true,
        stateSave: true,
        stateDuration: 0,

        columnDefs: [
            { "type": "date-uk", targets: [ edit_date_col_num, entry_date_col_num ] }
        ],

        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print',
            {
                extend: 'colvis',
                collectionLayout: 'fixed four-column',
                postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ]
            }
        ],

        language: {
            "emptyTable":     "No results match your search",
            "zeroRecords": "No results found",
            //"processing": "<div align='center'><img src='/static/ajax-loader.gif'></div>",
            //"loadingRecords": "<div align='center'><img src='/static/ajax-loader.gif'></div>",
        },

        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            "url": EE.BASE + "&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=ion&method=ajax_results",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        columns: [
        <?php
        foreach($columns AS $key => $val)
        {
            $visible_cols = array('field_id_325', 'field_id_326', 'field_id_697', 'field_id_649', 'field_id_689', 'field_id_632', 'entry_date', 'edit_date', 'field_id_698', 'field_id_666');

            $visible = 'false';
            if(in_array($key,$visible_cols))
            {
                $visible = 'true';  
            }
            echo '{';
            echo '  "visible": '.$visible.',';
            echo '  "data": "'.$key.'",';
            echo '  "class": "'.$key.'",';
            echo '},';
        }
        ?>
        ],
        <?php
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        $action = $this->input->get('action');
        if(isset($action) && $action == 'load' && isset($id) && $id != '') :
        ?>
        "stateLoadCallback": function (settings) {
            var o;

            // Send an Ajax request to the server to get the data. Note that
            // this is a synchronous request since the data is expected back from the
            // function
            $.ajax( {
                "url": EE.BASE + "&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=ion&method=state_save&action=load&id=<?php echo $id;?>",
                "async": false,
                "dataType": "json",
                "success": function (response) {
                    response = JSON.parse(response);
                    //console.log(response);
                    o = response;
                }
            });

            return o;
        },
        <?php
        endif;
        ?>

        initComplete: function (settings) {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;

                // Get the column number
                var col_num = column[0][0];

                // Do not do a select for date fields
                if(col_num ==edit_date_col_num || col_num ==entry_date_col_num)
                {
                    var date_range = $('from <input name="edit_date_min" id="edit_date_min"/>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                        .on( 'keyup', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? ''+val+'' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        } );
                }
                else
                {
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        } );

                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    } );

                }
            } );

            // Need to re-apply the selection to the select dropdowns
            var colsSearch = settings.aoPreSearchCols;
            var cols = settings.aoColumns;

            // Iterate through all cols to assign value to select/input fields
            for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++)
            {
                if(cols[i].bVisible == true)
                {
                    var cell_class = cols[i].class;

                    var value = colsSearch[i].sSearch;

                    if(value!='')
                    {
                        value = value.replace("^", "").replace("$","").replace("\\/", "/").replace("\\/", "/");
                        $("."+cell_class).find(":input").val(value);
                    }

                }
            }

        },

    } );


    // Save a datatables state by clicking the save button
    $( ".save_state" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        table.destroy();
        $('.mainTable').DataTable( {

            colReorder: true,
            stateSave: true,
            stateDuration: 0,

            "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {

                var save_name = $('.save_name').val();

                // Send an Ajax request to the server with the state object
                $.ajax( {
                    "url": EE.BASE + "&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=ion&method=state_save&action=save&save_name="+save_name,
                    "data": data,
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "success": function (response)
                    {
                        //console.log(response);
                    }
                } );

            },


        });


        //table.state.save();
        window.location.replace(EE.BASE + "&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=ion&method=applications");
    });


    $( ".clear_state" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        table.state.clear();
        window.location.replace(EE.BASE + "&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=ion&method=applications");
    });


    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            var iFini = document.getElementById('edit_date_min').value;
            var iStartDateCol = edit_date_col_num;

            iFini=iFini.substring(6,10) + iFini.substring(3,5)+ iFini.substring(0,2);

            var datofini=aData[iStartDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iStartDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iStartDateCol].substring(0,2);

            if ( iFini === "" )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if ( iFini <= datofini)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
            console.log("Search: "+iFini);
            console.log("Date: "+datofini);
        }
    );


    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#edit_date_min, #edit_date_max').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );


} );
```

Comment: You should really provide some code, an example of what you are talking about. It seems at little bit odd to ask people to visualize or imagine a programming problem on a programming Q&A site, completely without just the hint of code.

Comment: because I dont think its related to my code, its just a problem with datatables so wanted to know if others have a solution. I have added my code anyway.